# Change 0 to False and 1 to True in Python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataset, df, where I would like to convert values in specific columns to the string: TRUE, if it contains 1 and FALSE if it contains 0.

Data

```
Id    group

1     0
1     1
```

Desired output

```
 Id    group

   TRUE  FALSE
   TRUE  TRUE
```

Doing

```
  df[['Id', 'group']].replace([0]), 'False')
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: `df['group'] = df['group'].astype(bool)`. If you want to do so for `id`: `df = df.astype(bool)`.

Comment: Like the answer in the dupe, just the opposite (`.astype(bool)`)